# how to determine slow queries?

Tags: mysql, indexing, database-management, mysql-slow-query-log

My site is experiencing a really slow loading time. I have suspected that it might be javascript or php that causes longer loading time but i have tested my  site in YSlow and its grade is B which i think is not bad.

Now i want to check my database if something is wrong with queries, database indexing that causes my site to load slower.

Is there some tutorials or tricks i might read or try to test database to figure out if there is slow queries? Any tips for database management?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I always fall back to 2 mantras for faster query execution -

1. Indexes, indexes and indexes.
2. Try to get rid of `JOINS` as much as possible.

There are some tried and tested methods to weed out slow queries. You need to turn on [slow query log](http://www.ducea.com/2006/11/06/identifying-mysql-slow-queries/). This logs all those queries which take more than x seconds to execute. x is specified by you in mysql.conf.

Once the slow queries start logging in the log. You can analyse each query using [`EXPLAIN`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/explain.html) and appropriately add indexes to speedy the query execution.

Comment: thanks for the answer. but what is the best x seconds i could set for the production server, and what is the best x seconds to set on my local development server? any idea? thanks

Comment: the real true value of `x` really varies and depends on the perf you want. For example Google Adsense runs on mysql and I know for a fact that anything taking more than 500ms is deemed slow. But most of us are ok if the query takes 1sec. You need to ask yourself this - if I were the user whats the max time I would wait on this website?

Comment: It might not be a bad idea to set it to 0 (capture everything) and run the log through a tool, like [pt-query-digest](http://www.percona.com/doc/percona-toolkit/2.1/pt-query-digest.html)

Comment: what @TheVedge said is fine but be careful that even in a moderately trafficked website this will make the query log big very fast. Plus your disk I/O's would be going through the roof.

Comment: yeah i though of that also. although my client have enough disk space to store logs but i know it could be as big as 1Gb+. and how do i check that so big log? @Srikar thanks for that facts.

Comment: one way is to manually check the logs. But if its big you are better off taking the help of a slow query log analyzer like - `mysqldumpslow`. all the best.

Answer (score 0):

I have a thin database abstraction layer on top of PDO (formerly on top of MySQL) that I've baked simple query logging into which I can switch on and off - it allows me to get a report of the queries and how long each one took.  Thus rather than having a simple cut-off - something is either a long query or it's not - I get to see all my query times.

MySQL's slow query log is good<strike>, but its one-second resolution is not enough for my needs.  To me, a lot of the time, a query that takes 200 milliseconds is an indication of something wrong</strike>.

*I'm showing my age here.  After a quick check of the MySQL manual, it turns out that MySQL's `long_query_time` can be specified down to microsecond resolution since MySQL 5.1.27!  Nonetheless, my method is still handy.*

Comment: can you share the method you are using? i would be helpfull, really helpfull.

Comment: Well it's all pretty embedded in my own DB handling code so it may be of limited use to others.  [Here](https://github.com/trr/bluestone/blob/master/db_connection.inc.php) and [here](https://github.com/trr/bluestone/blob/master/debug.inc.php) is the code in its entirety = look for the use of `debug->starttask(` - the debug class logs everything and I can get all it logged later as $debug->getnoticestext()

Comment: I will also try this one, i will use any possible method available to do this. thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Good tutorial for sql performance - [focused on MySql](http://www.slideshare.net/techdude/how-to-kill-mysql-performance). For joins, if you can't get rid of them - use the right one: LEFT JOIN, RIGHT, INNER, OUTER